# HBase : Cant create table, Who to blame: HMaster or Zookeeper?

Tags: hbase, apache-zookeeper

Im getting "mixed messages" in the errors when creating a table in a simple hbase two node cluster.

1) My HMaster is clearly running:

> 21519 Manager
>   14748 HMaster
>   25110 Jps
>   9887 QuorumPeerMain
>   15473 HRegionServer
>   14062 ServiceMain
>   5702 Bootstrap

2) But when I try to create a table:

create 't1','f1'

I get a master initializing exception.

3) However, oddly, when i run this in -d mode, the logs seem to report security, rather than " master initializing " errors.

My question:  Is this a security error ? A zookeeper error?  Or an error on the HMaster?  And why is it that, with debug mode, the logs generally are referring to zookeeper security, whereas with the normal mode, the exception stack trace points to HMaster initialization failure?

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/hbase/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/zookeeper/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
13/09/24 18:22:16 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:zookeeper.version=3.4.5-Intel-20143, built on 08/28/2013 14:43 GMT
13/09/24 18:22:16 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:host.name=mrg5.lab.bos.redhat.com
13/09/24 18:22:16 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.version=1.6.0_31
13/09/24 18:22:16 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
13/09/24 18:22:16 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.home=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_31/jre
13/09/24 18:22:16 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.class.path=/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../conf:/usr/java/latest/lib/tools.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/..:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../hbase-0.94.7-Intel.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../hbase-0.94.7-Intel-tests.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../hbase.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/activation-1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/asm-3.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/avro-1.7.4-Intel.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/avro-ipc-1.7.4-Intel.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/commons-daemon-1.0.13.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/commons-digester-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/commons-el-1.0.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/commons-io-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/commons-lang-2.5.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/commons-logging-api-1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/commons-math-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/commons-net-3.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/core-3.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/glusterfs-hadoop.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/gmbal-api-only-3.0.0-b023.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/grizzly-framework-2.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/grizzly-framework-2.1.1-tests.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/grizzly-http-2.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/grizzly-http-server-2.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/grizzly-http-servlet-2.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/grizzly-rcm-2.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/guice-3.0.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/guice-servlet-3.0.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/hadoop-annotations.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/hadoop-common.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/hadoop-crypto.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/high-scale-lib-1.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/httpclient-4.1.3.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/httpcore-4.1.3.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/im-key.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jackson-xc-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jamon-runtime-2.3.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jasper-compiler-5.5.23.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jasper-runtime-5.5.23.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/javax.inject-1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/javax.servlet-3.0.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jaxb-api-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jersey-client-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jersey-core-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jersey-grizzly2-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jersey-guice-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jersey-json-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jersey-server-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jersey-test-framework-core-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jersey-test-framework-grizzly2-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jets3t-0.6.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jettison-1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jruby-complete-1.6.5.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jsch-0.1.42.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/json-simple-1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jsp-2.1-6.1.14.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jsp-api-2.1-6.1.14.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jsp-api-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/junit-4.10-HBASE-1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/libthrift-0.9.0.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/management-api-3.0.0-b012.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/metrics-core-2.1.2.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/netty-3.4.0.Final.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/protobuf-java-2.4.0a.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/protobuf-java.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/servlet-api-2.5-20081211.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/servlet-api-2.5-6.1.14.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/stax-api-1.0.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/velocity-1.7.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/xz-1.0.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/zookeeper.jar:/etc/hadoop/conf:/*:/lib/*:/usr/lib/zookeeper/zookeeper.jar:/usr/lib/zookeeper/zookeeper-3.4.5-Intel.jar:/usr/lib/zookeeper/lib/jline-0.9.94.jar:/usr/lib/zookeeper/lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar:/usr/lib/zookeeper/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar:/usr/lib/zookeeper/lib/netty-3.2.2.Final.jar:/usr/lib/zookeeper/lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar::/etc/hadoop/conf:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/stax-api-1.0.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/xz-1.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jettison-1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/avro-1.7.4-Intel.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jasper-compiler-5.5.23.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-logging-api-1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jersey-server-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jets3t-0.6.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jasper-runtime-5.5.23.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jersey-core-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-io-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-el-1.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-net-3.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/protobuf-java-2.4.0a.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jackson-xc-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/zookeeper-3.4.5-Intel.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-digester-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/hpc.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-lang-2.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jsp-api-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/json-simple-1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/imkey-2.0.4-Intel.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/lustre.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-math-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jersey-json-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/activation-1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jsch-0.1.42.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//hadoop-common.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//hadoop-common-2.0.4-Intel-tests.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//hadoop-auth.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//hadoop-annotations.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//hadoop-common-2.0.4-Intel.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//hadoop-crypto-1.0.0-Intel.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//hadoop-annotations-2.0.4-Intel.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//hadoop-auth-2.0.4-Intel.jar::/usr/lib/hbase/hbase.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/conf:/usr/lib/zookeeper/zookeeper.jar:/etc/hbase/conf:/usr/lib/hbase/lib/protobuf-java.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/./:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jersey-server-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jasper-runtime-5.5.23.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jersey-core-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/commons-io-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/commons-daemon-1.0.13.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/commons-el-1.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/protobuf-java-2.4.0a.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/commons-lang-2.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jsp-api-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/.//hadoop-hdfs-bkjournal.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/.//hadoop-hdfs-2.0.4-Intel-tests.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/.//hadoop-hdfs.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/.//hadoop-hdfs-2.0.4-Intel.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/.//hadoop-hdfs-bkjournal-2.0.4-Intel.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/netty-3.5.11.Final.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/aspectjrt-1.6.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/hamcrest-core-1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/xz-1.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/avro-1.7.4-Intel.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/guice-servlet-3.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/commons-logging-api-1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/jersey-server-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/aspectjtools-1.6.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/jersey-core-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/commons-io-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/javax.inject-1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/protobuf-java-2.4.0a.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/junit-4.10.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/jersey-guice-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/guice-3.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-server-resourcemanager-2.0.4-Intel.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-api-2.0.4-Intel.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-server-resourcemanager.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-applications-distributedshell.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-client.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-server-tests-2.0.4-Intel.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-server-tests.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-server-common-2.0.4-Intel.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-applications-unmanaged-am-launcher.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy-2.0.4-Intel.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-site-2.0.4-Intel.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-common.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-site.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-client-2.0.4-Intel.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager-2.0.4-Intel.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-common-2.0.4-Intel.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-api.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-server-common.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-applications-unmanaged-am-launcher-2.0.4-Intel.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-applications-distributedshell-2.0.4-Intel.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/netty-3.5.11.Final.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/hamcrest-core-1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/xz-1.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/avro-1.7.4-Intel.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/guice-servlet-3.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/commons-logging-api-1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/jersey-server-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/jersey-client-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/jersey-core-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/commons-io-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/javax.inject-1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/protobuf-java-2.4.0a.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/junit-4.10.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/jersey-guice-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/imkey-2.0.4-Intel.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/guice-3.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-plugins.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-datajoin.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.0.4-Intel-tests.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-mapreduce-examples.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-mapreduce-client-core.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-rumen-2.0.4-Intel.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-distcp.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle-2.0.4-Intel.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.0.4-Intel.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-plugins-2.0.4-Intel.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-datajoin-2.0.4-Intel.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-archives.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.0.4-Intel.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-mapreduce-client-app-2.0.4-Intel.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-distcp-2.0.4-Intel.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-extras-2.0.4-Intel.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-mapreduce-client-app.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-mapreduce-client-common.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-streaming.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-rumen.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.0.4-Intel.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-extras.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-archives-2.0.4-Intel.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-streaming-2.0.4-Intel.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-gridmix.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-mapreduce-client-common-2.0.4-Intel.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-gridmix-2.0.4-Intel.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-2.0.4-Intel.jar
13/09/24 18:22:16 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.library.path=/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/native/Linux-amd64-64
13/09/24 18:22:16 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp
13/09/24 18:22:16 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.compiler=<NA>
13/09/24 18:22:16 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.name=Linux
13/09/24 18:22:16 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.arch=amd64
13/09/24 18:22:16 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.version=2.6.32-195.el6.x86_64
13/09/24 18:22:16 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.name=root
13/09/24 18:22:16 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.home=/root
13/09/24 18:22:16 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.dir=/root
13/09/24 18:22:16 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=mrg6.lab.bos.redhat.com:2181,mrg5.lab.bos.redhat.com:2181 sessionTimeout=180000 watcher=hconnection
13/09/24 18:22:16 DEBUG zookeeper.ClientCnxn: zookeeper.disableAutoWatchReset is false
13/09/24 18:22:16 INFO zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: The identifier of this process is 28067@mrg5.lab.bos.redhat.com
13/09/24 18:22:16 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server mrg6.lab.bos.redhat.com/10.16.43.12:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (Unable to locate a login configuration)
13/09/24 18:22:16 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to mrg6.lab.bos.redhat.com/10.16.43.12:2181, initiating session
13/09/24 18:22:16 DEBUG zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment request sent on mrg6.lab.bos.redhat.com/10.16.43.12:2181
13/09/24 18:22:16 DEBUG client.ZooKeeperSaslClient: Could not retrieve login configuration: java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to locate a login configuration
13/09/24 18:22:16 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server mrg6.lab.bos.redhat.com/10.16.43.12:2181, sessionid = 0x14151eaaf2e0156, negotiated timeout = 180000
13/09/24 18:22:16 DEBUG client.ZooKeeperSaslClient: Could not retrieve login configuration: java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to locate a login configuration
13/09/24 18:22:16 DEBUG client.ZooKeeperSaslClient: Could not retrieve login configuration: java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to locate a login configuration
13/09/24 18:22:16 DEBUG client.ZooKeeperSaslClient: Could not retrieve login configuration: java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to locate a login configuration
13/09/24 18:22:16 DEBUG client.ZooKeeperSaslClient: Could not retrieve login configuration: java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to locate a login configuration
13/09/24 18:22:16 DEBUG client.ZooKeeperSaslClient: Could not retrieve login configuration: java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to locate a login configuration
13/09/24 18:22:16 DEBUG client.ZooKeeperSaslClient: Could not retrieve login configuration: java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to locate a login configuration
13/09/24 18:22:16 DEBUG zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Reading reply sessionid:0x14151eaaf2e0156, packet:: clientPath:null serverPath:null finished:false header:: 1,3  replyHeader:: 1,21474837891,0  request:: '/hbase/hbaseid,F  response:: s{21474836518,21474836518,1380058871058,1380058871058,0,0,0,0,70,0,21474836518}
13/09/24 18:22:16 DEBUG client.ZooKeeperSaslClient: Could not retrieve login configuration: java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to locate a login configuration
13/09/24 18:22:16 DEBUG client.ZooKeeperSaslClient: Could not retrieve login configuration: java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to locate a login configuration
13/09/24 18:22:16 DEBUG client.ZooKeeperSaslClient: Could not retrieve login configuration: java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to locate a login configuration
13/09/24 18:22:16 DEBUG client.ZooKeeperSaslClient: Could not retrieve login configuration: java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to locate a login configuration
13/09/24 18:22:16 DEBUG client.ZooKeeperSaslClient: Could not retrieve login configuration: java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to locate a login configuration
13/09/24 18:22:16 DEBUG zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Reading reply sessionid:0x14151eaaf2e0156, packet:: clientPath:null serverPath:null finished:false header:: 2,4  replyHeader:: 2,21474837891,0  request:: '/hbase/hbaseid,F  response:: #ffffffff0001d3134373438406d7267352e6c61622e626f732e7265646861742e636f6d63306434323636302d376239632d343864392d616465392d623332326366616137396562,s{21474836518,21474836518,1380058871058,1380058871058,0,0,0,0,70,0,21474836518}
13/09/24 18:22:16 DEBUG client.ZooKeeperSaslClient: Could not retrieve login configuration: java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to locate a login configuration
13/09/24 18:22:16 DEBUG client.ZooKeeperSaslClient: Could not retrieve login configuration: java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to locate a login configuration
13/09/24 18:22:16 DEBUG client.ZooKeeperSaslClient: Could not retrieve login configuration: java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to locate a login configuration
13/09/24 18:22:16 DEBUG client.ZooKeeperSaslClient: Could not retrieve login configuration: java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to locate a login configuration
13/09/24 18:22:16 DEBUG client.ZooKeeperSaslClient: Could not retrieve login configuration: java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to locate a login configuration
13/09/24 18:22:16 DEBUG zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Reading reply sessionid:0x14151eaaf2e0156, packet:: clientPath:null serverPath:null finished:false header:: 3,3  replyHeader:: 3,21474837891,0  request:: '/hbase/master,T  response:: s{21474836513,21474836513,1380058869212,1380058869212,0,0,0,90443535927345156,79,0,21474836513}
13/09/24 18:22:16 DEBUG client.ZooKeeperSaslClient: Could not retrieve login configuration: java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to locate a login configuration
13/09/24 18:22:16 DEBUG client.ZooKeeperSaslClient: Could not retrieve login configuration: java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to locate a login configuration
13/09/24 18:22:16 DEBUG client.ZooKeeperSaslClient: Could not retrieve login configuration: java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to locate a login configuration
13/09/24 18:22:16 DEBUG client.ZooKeeperSaslClient: Could not retrieve login configuration: java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to locate a login configuration
13/09/24 18:22:16 DEBUG client.ZooKeeperSaslClient: Could not retrieve login configuration: java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to locate a login configuration
13/09/24 18:22:16 DEBUG zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Reading reply sessionid:0x14151eaaf2e0156, packet:: clientPath:null serverPath:null finished:false header:: 4,4  replyHeader:: 4,21474837891,0  request:: '/hbase/master,T  response:: #ffffffff0001d3134373438406d7267352e6c61622e626f732e7265646861742e636f6d006d7267352e6c61622e626f732e7265646861742e636f6d2c36303030302c31333830303538383636333235,s{21474836513,21474836513,1380058869212,1380058869212,0,0,0,90443535927345156,79,0,21474836513}
13/09/24 18:22:16 DEBUG client.ZooKeeperSaslClient: Could not retrieve login configuration: java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to locate a login configuration
13/09/24 18:22:16 DEBUG client.ZooKeeperSaslClient: Could not retrieve login configuration: java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to locate a login configuration
13/09/24 18:22:16 DEBUG client.ZooKeeperSaslClient: Could not retrieve login configuration: java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to locate a login configuration
13/09/24 18:22:16 DEBUG client.ZooKeeperSaslClient: Could not retrieve login configuration: java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to locate a login configuration
13/09/24 18:22:16 DEBUG client.ZooKeeperSaslClient: Could not retrieve login configuration: java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to locate a login configuration
13/09/24 18:22:16 DEBUG zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Reading reply sessionid:0x14151eaaf2e0156, packet:: clientPath:null serverPath:null finished:false header:: 5,3  replyHeader:: 5,21474837891,0  request:: '/hbase/root-region-server,T  response:: s{21474836544,21474836544,1380058877762,1380058877762,0,0,0,0,77,0,21474836544}
13/09/24 18:22:16 DEBUG client.ZooKeeperSaslClient: Could not retrieve login configuration: java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to locate a login configuration
13/09/24 18:22:16 DEBUG client.ZooKeeperSaslClient: Could not retrieve login configuration: java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to locate a login configuration
13/09/24 18:22:16 DEBUG client.ZooKeeperSaslClient: Could not retrieve login configuration: java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to locate a login configuration
13/09/24 18:22:16 DEBUG client.ZooKeeperSaslClient: Could not retrieve login configuration: java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to locate a login configuration
13/09/24 18:22:16 DEBUG client.ZooKeeperSaslClient: Could not retrieve login configuration: java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to locate a login configuration
13/09/24 18:22:16 DEBUG zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Reading reply sessionid:0x14151eaaf2e0156, packet:: clientPath:null serverPath:null finished:false header:: 6,4  replyHeader:: 6,21474837891,0  request:: '/hbase/root-region-server,T  response:: #ffffffff0001d3135343733406d7267352e6c61622e626f732e7265646861742e636f6d6d7267352e6c61622e626f732e7265646861742e636f6d2c36303032302c31333830303538383730303835,s{21474836544,21474836544,1380058877762,1380058877762,0,0,0,0,77,0,21474836544}
13/09/24 18:22:16 DEBUG client.ZooKeeperSaslClient: Could not retrieve login configuration: java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to locate a login configuration
13/09/24 18:22:16 DEBUG client.ZooKeeperSaslClient: Could not retrieve login configuration: java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to locate a login configuration
13/09/24 18:22:16 DEBUG client.ZooKeeperSaslClient: Could not retrieve login configuration: java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to locate a login configuration
13/09/24 18:22:16 DEBUG client.ZooKeeperSaslClient: Could not retrieve login configuration: java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to locate a login configuration
13/09/24 18:22:16 DEBUG client.ZooKeeperSaslClient: Could not retrieve login configuration: java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to locate a login configuration
13/09/24 18:22:16 DEBUG client.ZooKeeperSaslClient: Could not retrieve login configuration: java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to locate a login configuration
13/09/24 18:22:16 DEBUG zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Reading reply sessionid:0x14151eaaf2e0156, packet:: clientPath:null serverPath:null finished:false header:: 7,3  replyHeader:: 7,21474837891,0  request:: '/hbase,F  response:: s{21474836500,21474836500,1380058867429,1380058867429,0,13,0,0,0,13,21474836544}
13/09/24 18:22:16 DEBUG client.ZooKeeperSaslClient: Could not retrieve login configuration: java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to locate a login configuration
```

Answer (score 0):

Please shut down HBase, make sure your Hadoop is running fine (fsck, put/get files). Then clean up the HBase log directory. Restart HBase. Sorry it is not a pointed answer but I think there might be some problems in opening the log files. THe above procedure has stood me in good stead for quite some time I have been playing with HBase.

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest that your Hadoop cluster has accepted that you have nodes=1, check that **safenode** state has not been invoked

If you are in safe mode - then you can leave this (slightly dependent on your hadoop version) with

```
hadoop dfsadmin -safemode leave
```

You should however check your hadoop settings - plus your hfs fsck settings

```
  hadoop fsck /
```

I hope that helps